# Node.JS requests with rejectUnauthorized as false

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to use the `request` module for Node.js to formulate a HTTPS GET request. The corresponding code using the `https` module is as follows:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    hostname: url,
    path: path,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
    port: 8443,
    method: 'POST'
  };

https.get(options, function(response) {
    var body = ''; 
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        var content = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(content);
    });
});
```

I attempted to rewrite this code using the `request` module as follows:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: url,
    strictSSL: false
}

request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

However, this gives me an error `{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET', sslError: undefined }`

What would be the `request` equivalent of `rejectUnauthorized: false`?

Answer (score 7):

**This will might help you.**

```
let request = require( 'request' ).defaults({rejectUnauthorized:false});
```

Answer (score 5):

The `request` module in Node.js has the option `secureProtocol` even though it is not documented.

This can be used as follows:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: url,
    strictSSL: false,
    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
}

request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an agent to your request call. This allows you to add `rejectUnauthorized` like before:

```
const request = require('request');
const https = require('https');

var agent = new https.Agent({
  host: URL_HOST,
  port: '443',
  path: '/',
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

var options = {
  url: url,
  agent: agent
};

request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the value of URL_HOST is not equal to the value of url ?

Answer (score 0):

add these two line:

```
...
rejectUnauthorized: false,
requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
agent: false,//add when working with https sites
...
```

that works for me.